# Trouble running ipfs daemon

Tags: ipfs

Got IPFS installed on a new computer and got problems running:

ipfs deamon

It returns Error: lock /Users/yenan/.ipfs/repo.lock: someone else has the lock

This wasn't a problem on a previous computer. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If the file `repo.lock` exists, it normally means that the IPFS daemon is already running. It could also be left over from an IPFS daemon that was terminated without letting it shut down properly (e. g. with `kill -9`).

Make sure that no IPFS processes are running, then remove the lock file manually and restart the daemon:

```
killall ipfs
rm /Users/yenan/.ipfs/repo.lock
ipfs daemon
```

Comment: How can I remove the repo.lock file when running IPFS Kubo in a docker container?
I tried to create a new entrypoint.sh script to delete the file at startup but no luck so far. 

Also this repo.lock is owned by root and not the ipfs user...